# Breeze.js and Tasypie : Handling non OData API

Tags: javascript, breeze

I saw in a lot a different post that [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com) is supposed to work with any http served resource.

In [Breeze Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/introduction), you always have references to OData urls.

For example, the following breeze code:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery()
                  .from("Customers")
                  .where("CompanyName", "startsWith", "C")
                  .orderBy("CompanyName");
```

Will result in the following OData request:

```
http://www.example.com/api/Northwind/Customers?$filter=startswith(CompanyName,'C') eq true&$orderby=CompanyName
```

Well That's nice, but I'm Using Django+Tastypie and it does not support OData parameters, so this request fail on my backend.

How am I supposed to change the way breeze.js generate it's request to API backend server? Did I missed something in Breeze doc? IThank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Edmunds sample. In that sample, the breeze client makes requests of a service that does not speak OData.

If your service doesn't support the OData query syntax, then you can't use the LINQ-like query expressions on the breeze client. You can't use "where" and "orderBy". That's the deal.

You can still compose a query for any service endpoint that accepts a GET request. `EntityQuery.from(anyURL)` should work fine. You can still leverage the other benefits of Breeze client-side data management - caching, validation, entity navigation, etc. But you'll probably have to construct the metadata on the client and handle query and save yourself.